# How to use except and any with strings instead of classes

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

Like said above how would I, I have some code using linq and except and any(). Currently I use items(a class), to be identified and such, but this is causing problems, so I would like them to be identified by strings instead, but im not sure how. The two functions with the code are: ContainsAllItems, and the other one is in the craft function.
Thanks!

EDIT; To make more clear just in case, right now it checks the items in two lists, instead of that what im asking is how to make it that it checks the itemname of the items in the lists instead, but still make it have the same effect, so it would destroy items and check items and make sure when destroying that not more than needed are destroyed.

If you would not want to look through the code here are the two lines:

```
public static bool ContainsAllItems(List<Item> a, List<Item> b)
    {
        return !b.Except(a).Any();
    }
```

and

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
                list = InventoryItems.Except(Recipe.InputItem).ToList();
                InventoryItems = list;
```

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class PlayerInventory : MonoBehaviour {

    public int MaxInventory = 26;

    public List<Item> InventoryItems = new List<Item>();

    void OnGUI(){
        if (GUILayout.Button ("+5 Wood")) {
            AddItem(ItemConstructors.Wood());
            AddItem(ItemConstructors.Wood());    
            AddItem(ItemConstructors.Wood());    
            AddItem(ItemConstructors.Wood());    
            AddItem(ItemConstructors.Wood());
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button ("Craft Wall")) {
            Craft(CraftingRecipes.WoodenWall());
        }

    }


    public void AddItem(Item _item){
        if (InventoryItems.Count < MaxInventory) {
            InventoryItems.Add(_item);
            //SaveItems();
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(Item _item){
        InventoryItems.Remove (_item);
    }

    public void UseItem(Item _item){
        if (_item.ItemType == "Food") {
            ConsumeItem(_item);
        }
        SaveItems();
    }

    public void ConsumeItem(Item _item){
        if (_item.ItemDur > 1) {
            _item.ItemDur--; 
        }
        else if(_item.ItemDur <= 1){
            RemoveItem(_item);
        }
    }

    public void SaveItems(){
        for (int i = 0; i<MaxInventory; i++) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Itemn"+i,InventoryItems[i].ItemName); 
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Itemt"+i,InventoryItems[i].ItemType);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Itemv"+i,InventoryItems[i].ItemValue);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Itemd"+i,InventoryItems[i].ItemDur);
        }
//LoadItems ();
    }
    public void LoadItems(){
        InventoryItems.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i<MaxInventory; i++) {
            Item it = new Item();
            it.ItemName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Itemn"+i);
            it.ItemType = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Itemt"+i);
            it.ItemValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Itemv"+i);
            it.ItemDur = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Itemd"+i);
            if(it.ItemName.Length <= 2 && it.ItemType.Length <= 2){
            }
            else{
                InventoryItems.Add(it);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Craft(CraftingItem Recipe){
        bool canCraft = ContainsAllItems (InventoryItems,Recipe.InputItem);
        if(canCraft){
            if(InventoryItems.Count < MaxInventory){
                List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
                list = InventoryItems.Except(Recipe.InputItem).ToList();
                InventoryItems = list;
                AddItem(Recipe.OutputItem);
            }
            else{
                Debug.Log("Not enough space!");
            }
        }
        else{
            Debug.Log("Invalid Items.");
        }
    }

    public static bool ContainsAllItems(List<Item> a, List<Item> b)
    {
        return !b.Except(a).Any();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is [Except overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes IEqualityComparer, would that work for you?

Comment: I guess you will be better off using another data structure for your inventory, perhaps a Dictionary holding a counter for each type of inventory item.

Comment: I don't think checking for a name is good idea. Names change when you do internationalization. Maybe rather go for an ID and yes, use a Dictionary. This makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Could you give and example of using a dictionary, I have never used one before, and do I modify the sort method too when using dictonary?